# Show that $|\int_X f d \mu|= \int_X|f|d\mu$ if and only if there is a constant $\alpha$ such that $|f| = \alpha f$ a.e. on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis

***Problem:* Let $f \in L^1(\mu)$. Show that $|\int_X f d \mu|= \int_X|f|d\mu$ if and only if there is a constant $\alpha$ such that $|f| = \alpha f$ a.e. on $X$.**

My Solution is below but can anyone check this implication $\Rightarrow$

$"\Leftarrow"$ Let $\alpha= sign(f)$ be a constant such that $|f|=\alpha f$ then $$\int_X |f|d \mu = \int_X sign(f) f d\mu= sign(f) \int_X f = \Big|\int_Xf d\mu\Big|$$
$"\Rightarrow"$ Let $f \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $|\int_X f d \mu|= \int_X|f|d\mu$. We want to find a constant $\alpha$ such that $|f|= \alpha f$. By definition of absolute value
$$\Big|\int_X f d\mu \Big|=
\begin{cases}
- \int_X f d\mu & \text{ if } \int_X f d\mu<0\\
\int_X f d\mu & \text{ if } \int_X f d\mu>0
\end{cases}(*)
$$
But we know by Integral Comparison Test that $$\Big|\int_X f d \mu\Big| \leq \int_X |f|(**)$$
From (*) and (**) we have $-f \leq |f|$ and $f\leq |f|$ then must have $|f| = sign(f) f$ and $\alpha= sign(f)$

Comment: How do * and ** imply your last set of inequalities?  Edit:  even if they do, I'm not sure I see that $\alpha$ is a constant.  How do you know that it doesn't vary?

Comment: We have always $\pm f \le |f|$... in the $\implies$ direction, you can't select $\alpha$. It is given. Your argument needs to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{cases} f=f^+-f^- &\\ |f|=f^++f^-\end{cases}$ and $\begin{cases}I^+=\int_X f^+d\mu\\ I^-=\int_X f^-d\mu\end{cases}$

$\displaystyle \int_X |f|d\mu=I^++I^-=\bigg|\int_X fd\mu\bigg|=\pm(I^+-I^-)$

- positive case : $I^++I^-=I^+-I^-\iff 2I^-=0\iff f^-=0\quad\mu$-pp on $X$
- negative case : $I^++I^-=-I^++I^-\iff 2I^+=0\iff f^+=0\quad\mu$-pp on $X$

And this can be rewritten $|f|=\alpha f$ with $\alpha=\pm 1$. Beware that the equality is only true $\mu$-pp on $X$.

Comment: why is $\int_X |f|d\mu=I^++I^- =\bigg|\int_X fd\mu\bigg|=\pm(I^+-I^-)$
I'm a little confused about  the part  $I^++I^- =\bigg|\int_X fd\mu\bigg|$

Comment: @Cnine it is a consequence of $\int_x |f|d\mu=|\int_x fd\mu|$ which is the problem asked by OP. I suppose it happens, and I gain constraints on $I^+$ and $I^-$.

Comment: oh okay, I get it now,  we made that assumption in the "$\Rightarrow$ "direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Without loss of generality let $\int_X f \, d\mu \ge 0$. Then, we have
$$ \int_X \underbrace{|f| - f}_{\ge 0} \, d\mu, $$
which is $0$ if and only if $|f| - f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: this give $\alpha=1$?

Comment: @Lucas in that case, yes.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow your hint.

Comment: @Lucas where do you stuck?